# how to know which version of MS Office 2013 one is using?

Tags: microsoft-office

MS Office 2013 has various versions, like standard, home, professional etc. How do I check which version is in a particular system?

Comment: Really? Seriously?

Comment: @joeqwerty, where does it state that in the help sections?

Comment: Where does what state what?

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for the down votes... I feel so grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open one of the Office programs (like Word).
- Click the *File* tab.
- Choose *Account*.
- The info you seek will be listed on that page under "Product Information":

[image: Word Product Info Shot]

Comment: Its astonishing that an answer gets two upvotes but the question has 4 down votes...